# Adding multiple buttons + receiving touchUpInside event inside UICollectionViewCell SWIFT programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to build a CollectionView for a list all programmatically in Swift without using Storyboard. I was able to add a tap gesture event to the cell.

However, When I added a set of buttons to the UICollectionViewCell's contentView, the buttons do not receive any touch events.

Inside Controller

```
let sampleCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: (..), collectionViewLayout: layout)

//Register the UICollectionViewCell inside UICollectionView
sampleCollectionView.registerClass(sampleCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "sampleCell")

//Add Tap Gesture event to the cell area
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapForCell:") 
sampleCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

func handleTapForCell(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   //I can break in here
}
```

Inside CollectionViewCell

```
class sampleCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{ 

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
  var buttonBack = UIButton(type: .Custom)
  buttonBack.addTarget(self, action: "actionGoBack:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  ..
  self.contentView.addSubview(buttonBack)
 }

 func actionGoBack(sender: UIButton){
    //I want to get my touch action break in here when I tap right inside the button but it won't
 }         
}
```

Is CollectionViewCell suited to accept more than one type of tap action (tapping on the whole cell versus multiple buttons inside cell)?

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Disable Tap Gesture on CollectionView, still not receiving events
2. Without adding tap events to button, I tried to find the "location" of tap inside the cell, then check if this is in bounds of the button, if so, fire an event. I find this work around to be buggy when I try to add animation or scroll.

Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Comment: Why did you add a tap recogniser to the cell? UICollectionView has callback function for didSelect right?

Comment: Yes, I interchanged didSelect / tapGesure at the cell level - no effect for the buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the gesture recognizer to not block the touches in subview

```
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

You can also implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and set yourself as delegate. Then you can implement shouldReceiveTouch

```
optional public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
```

There you can check which view is targeted and return false if you don't want to react to the touch in the cells gesture recognizer.

Comment: Brilliant. Just setting the tap. cancelsTouchesInView = false, got the event to recognize (I have to click twice). All i have to do now is to find that exact cell from resuable to handle my event. Thanks!