# Figure out which of multiple buttons in UICollectionView cell was tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my Swift code, I have a `UICollectionViewCell` with 3 buttons (all three have IBActions). From my `UICollectionViewController` I now want to "catch" the individual button taps.

I've followed this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338842/adding-multiple-buttons-receiving-touchupinside-event-inside-uicollectionviewc) and I can catch the UICollectionViewCell's touch-up inside up in my CollectionViewController with adding this line to the viewDidLoad

```
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

and with this function

```
func handleTapForCell(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
   //I can break in here
}
```

But the piece missing now is **how can I figure out which of the three buttons have been tapped**? I have set different tags on the buttons but I have not found any place on the gestureRecognizer dealing with these tags.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to detect which subview was tapped from handleTapForCell? If  yes here is objective C answer that should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225747/uitapgesturerecognizer-for-detecting-which-uiview-was-tapped-on-my-screen/38226252#38226252

Comment: But why use Tap gesture and not IBAction of button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you don't need to add Gesture on cell to get a button action of a tableviewCell. This code may help you:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Your tableviewCell code here

        //set tag of cell button
        cell.button1.tag = 1
        cell.button2.tag = 2
        cell.button3.tag = 3

        //add action of your cell button
        cell.button1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellButtonTapped:event:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.button2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellButtonTapped:event:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.button3.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cellButtonTapped:event:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        // return cell
    }

    func cellButtonTapped(sender:UIButton, event:AnyObject){

        let touches: NSSet = event.allTouches()!
        let touch = touches.anyObject()
        let currentTouchPosition: CGPoint = (touch?.locationInView(YOUR_TABLEVIEW_INSTANCE))!

        if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.YOUR_TABLEVIEW_INSTANCE.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!{

            if sender.tag == 1{
                //cell first button tap
            }else sender.tag == 2{
                //cell second button tap
            }
            else sender.tag == 3{
                //cell 3rd button tap
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked for me. Supercool. Thanks. 
Just in case somebody wants to use it with Swift 2: I have updated the selector line `cell.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.buttonTapped(_:event:")), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`
and in a CollectionView just change the indexPathForRowAt point with
`if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(currentTouchPosition)!{`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the protocol/delegate paradigm.

What you need to do is define a protocol in Custom cell. Then make the viewcontroller subscribe to the cell delegate.

Implement the IBActions inside the custom cell class. Call the delegate methods in the IBActions of the buttons. viewcontroller who is delegating for the cell will receive the callbacks for button taps inside the cell.